# Custom select shadow not hiding after choosing option - Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have this custom select, when it opens its option list there is a shadow on it, but when I choose an option and the list closes the shadow isn't hiding. This problem is happening only on Safari. Here's a sample:

**Edit:** The problem appears to happen only if there is another input field before it on the page.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.niceSelect = function(method) {

    // Methods
    if (typeof method === 'string') {
      if (method === 'update') {
        this.each(function() {
          var $select = $(this);
          var $dropdown = $(this).next('.nice-select');
          var open = $dropdown.hasClass('open');
          var focused = $select.parents('.form-group-select').hasClass('focused');

          if ($dropdown.length) {
            $dropdown.remove();
            create_nice_select($select);

            if (open) {
              $select.next().trigger('click');
            } else if (focused) {
              $select.parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused');
            }
          }
        });
      } else if (method === 'destroy') {
        this.each(function() {
          var $select = $(this);
          var $dropdown = $(this).next('.nice-select');

          if ($dropdown.length) {
            $dropdown.remove();
            $select.css('display', '');
          }
        });
        if ($('.nice-select').length === 0) {
          $(document).off('.nice_select');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Method "' + method + '" does not exist.');
      }
      return this;
    }

    // Hide native select
    this.hide();

    // Create custom markup
    this.each(function() {
      var $select = $(this);

      if (!$select.next().hasClass('nice-select')) {
        create_nice_select($select);
      }
    });
    function create_nice_select($select) {
      $select.after($('<div></div>')
        .addClass('nice-select')
        .addClass($select.attr('class') || '')
        .addClass($select.attr('disabled') ? 'disabled' : '')
        .attr('tabindex', $select.attr('disabled') ? null : '0')
        .html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>')
      );

      var $dropdown = $select.next();
      var $options = $select.find('option');
      var $optgroups = $select.find('optgroup');
      var $selected = $select.find('option:selected');

      $dropdown.find('.current').html($selected.data('display') || $selected.text());

      $options.each(function() {
        var $option = $(this);
        var display = $option.data('display');
        var group = $option.parents('optgroup').data('i');

        $dropdown.find('ul').append($('<li></li>')
          .attr('data-value', $option.val())
          .attr('data-display', (display || null))
          .attr('data-group', (group || null))
          .addClass('option' +
            ($option.is(':selected') ? ' selected' : '') +
            ($option.is(':disabled') ? ' disabled' : ''))
          .html($option.text())
        );
      });
      $optgroups.each(function(i, g) {
        label = $(g).attr('label');
        $dropdown.find('ul li').filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('group') === $(g).data('i');
          })
          .wrapAll('<div class="optgroup"/>')
          .parent()
          .prepend('<span class="label">' + label + '</span>');
      });
    }

    /* Event listeners */
    // Unbind existing events in case that the plugin has been initialized before
    $(document).off('.nice_select');

    // Open/close
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select', function() {
      var $dropdown = $(this);

      $('.nice-select').not($dropdown).removeClass('open');
      $dropdown.toggleClass('open');

      if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
        $dropdown.find('.option');
        $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
        $dropdown.find('.selected').addClass('focus');
      } else {
        $dropdown.focus();
      }
    });

    // Close when clicking outside
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', function(event) {

      if ($(event.target).closest('.nice-select').length === 0) {
        $('.nice-select').removeClass('open').find('.option');
      }
    });

    // Animation loading a page
    $('select').on('blur', function(e) {
      $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
    }).trigger('blur');

    // Option click
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select .option:not(.disabled)', function() {

      var $option = $(this);
      var $dropdown = $option.closest('.nice-select');

      $dropdown.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $option.addClass('selected');

      var text = $option.data('display') || $option.text();
      $dropdown.find('.current').text(text);

      $dropdown.prev('select').val($option.data('value')).trigger('change');

      // Animation
      $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', ($option.data('value') !== ''));
    });

    // Keyboard events
    $(document).on('keydown.nice_select', '.nice-select', function(event) {

      var $dropdown = $(this);
      var $focused_option = $($dropdown.find('.focus') || $dropdown.find('.list .option.selected'));

      // Space or Enter
      if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
        if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $focused_option.trigger('click');
        } else {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        }
        return false;

        // Down
      } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
        if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        } else {
          var $all_options = $dropdown.find(".option:not(.disabled)");
          var $next = $all_options.eq($all_options.index($focused_option) + 1);
          if ($next.length > 0) {
            $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
            $next.addClass('focus');
          }
        }
        return false;

        // Up
      } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        if (!$dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        } else {
          var $all_options = $dropdown.find(".option:not(.disabled)");
          var $prev = $all_options.eq($all_options.index($focused_option) - 1);
          if ($prev.length > 0) {
            $dropdown.find('.focus').removeClass('focus');
            $prev.addClass('focus');
          }
        }
        return false;

        // Esc
      } else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          $dropdown.trigger('click');
        }

        // Tab
      } else if (event.keyCode === 9) {
        if ($dropdown.hasClass('open')) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
$('select').niceSelect();
```

```css
.nice-select .list {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.form-group {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
}

.form-group::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}

.form-group.animate::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.control-label {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label,
.form-group-select.focused .control-label {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form_campos {
  height: 31px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #484848;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form_campos:hover,
.form_campos:focus {
  border-color: #0091FF;
}

.form_disabled,
.form_disabled:hover,
.form_disabled:focus {
  border-color: #D7D7D7;
}


/*====================================================================================================================*/


/* Select */


/*====================================================================================================================*/

.form-group-select.focused .control-label {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.form-group-select {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
}

.nice-select:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #0091FF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}

.nice-select.open::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.nice-select {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.nice-select.open {
  overflow: visible;
}

.nice-select span.current {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.optgroup span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.nice-select:hover,
.nice-select:focus {
  border-color: #0091FF;
}

.nice-select:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #484848;
  border-right: 2px solid #484848;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  width: 5px;
}

.nice-select.open:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.nice-select.open .list {
  color: #484848;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}

.nice-select.disabled {
  border-color: #ededed;
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nice-select.disabled:after {
  border-color: #cccccc;
}

.nice-select .list {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nice-select .list:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.nice-select .list:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

.nice-select .option {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 29px;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 7px solid #FFF;
}

.nice-select .option:hover,
.nice-select .focus {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-left: 7px solid #F65314;
}

.nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent !important;
}

.nice-select .option.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nice-select .option.disabled {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999;
  cursor: default;
}

.no-csspointerevents .nice-select .list {
  display: none;
}

.no-csspointerevents .nice-select.open .list {
  display: block;
}


/*====================================================================================================================*/


/* Grid */


/*====================================================================================================================*/

.row {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.row,
.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row>.column:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.column+.column {
  margin-left: 1.6%;
}

.column-1 {
  width: 6.86666666667%;
}

.column-2 {
  width: 15.3333333333%;
}

.column-3 {
  width: 23.8%;
}

.column-4 {
  width: 32.2666666667%;
}

.column-5 {
  width: 40.7333333333%;
}

.column-6 {
  width: 49.2%;
}

.column-7 {
  width: 57.6666666667%;
}

.column-8 {
  width: 66.1333333333%;
}

.column-9 {
  width: 74.6%;
}

.column-10 {
  width: 83.0666666667%;
}

.column-11 {
  width: 91.5333333333%;
}

.column-12 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}


/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .column-1,
  .column-2,
  .column-3,
  .column-4,
  .column-5,
  .column-6,
  .column-7,
  .column-8,
  .column-9,
  .column-10,
  .column-11,
  .column-12 {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  .column+.column {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .row:last-child .column:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Grid -->
<div class="row">
<div class='form-group column column-8'>
    <label class='control-label' for='nome'>NAME</label>
    <input type='text' class='form_campos autofocus' id='nome' name='nome'>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group-select column column-4'>
    <label class='control-label'>CHOOSE</label>
    <select name='choose'>
                    <option value="s">YES</option>  
                    <option value="n">NO</option>
                </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if there is a bug in Safari.
By fiddling around I found that if I remove

```
overflow: hidden;
```

from your CSS-class ".nice-select", it seems to work.

Please try it out.

Edit:
Try adding

```
display: none;
```

to ".nice-select .list"
and

```
display: block;
```

to ".nice-select.open .list"

Comment: If I remove the overflow: hidden and the select has many options, it creates a scroll on the page to fit all the options.

Comment: I edited my answer. The thing is, you won't be able to have opacity transitions. I am not able to accomplish both... I will investigate it further if you like.

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if I can make the transitions work again, but thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You could fade the list with jQuery's fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions. Or animate more props with jQuery's animate() function. By using jQuery you could leave the classes as they are now. But keep in mind, that animate() works internally with heavy usage of setTimeout. So, when overused, it will become a performance issue.